# StateListDrawable inside GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

After changing my code around ([first attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852585/updating-gridview-child)) I am having a similar problem. I have updated my getView() to execute the proper way.

```
@Override
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    Resources res = activity.getResources();

    if( convertView == null ) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = vi.inflate( R.layout.video_gallery_item, parent, false ); 
    }

    Bitmap bmp = getBitmap( videoIds[ position ] );

    /* This layer drawable will create a border around the image. This works */
    Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[ 2 ];
    layers[ 0 ] = new BitmapDrawable( res, bmp );
    layers[ 1 ] = res.getDrawable( R.drawable.border_selected );
    LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable( layers );

    /* Create the StateListDrawable */
    StateListDrawable drawable = new StateListDrawable();
    drawable.addState( StateSet.WILD_CARD, new BitmapDrawable( res, bmp ) );
    drawable.addState( new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_checked, android.R.attr.state_selected }, layerDrawable );
    ImageView v = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById( R.id.image );
    v.setImageDrawable( drawable );
    v.setAdjustViewBounds( true );
    thumbnails[ position ] = bmp;
    return convertView;
}
```

This adapter is being use on a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) called videoGallery:

```
videoGallery.setChoiceMode( GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL );
videoGallery.setMultiChoiceModeListener( new MultiChoiceModeListener() { ... }
```

The problem I am having is that the images do not change when they are selected on the GridView via long click. The action bar changes, my contextual menu appears, etc. I have also tried creating the StateListDrawable via XML with the same results. Thoughts?

**UPDATE**

Changing

```
drawable.addState( new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_checked, android.R.attr.state_selected }, layerDrawable );
```

to

```
drawable.addState( StateSet.WILD_CARD, layerDrawable );
```

in my getView() shows the border I am looking for. So maybe the StateListDrawable isn't getting the state change? Anybody have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out. There were a few problems with my states. First in the order:

```
drawable.addState( StateSet.WILD_CARD, new BitmapDrawable( res, bmp ) );
drawable.addState( new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_checked, android.R.attr.state_selected }, layerDrawable );
```

In the first `addState` I am using the wildcard. Because of this android would match this state before the one following that. Also, despite android saying the item is "checked" the actual state is "activated". So I changed the two lines to:

```
drawable.addState( new int[] { android.R.attr.state_activated }, layerDrawable );
drawable.addState( new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_activated }, new BitmapDrawable( res, bmp ) );
```

And it is working perfectly!